# Stroustroup: free(): double free detected in tcache 2 when implementing vector::reserve()

Tags: c++, raii

The code given in Bjarne Stroustrup - Programming Principles and Practice - Chapter 19.5.6 "RAII for vector" doesn't work when calling push_back() then reserve(). Separately they work fine.

I get this error "free(): double free detected in tcache 2"
With debugging I see that after calling swap() inside reserve() the variable b.elem[0] has
<error: Cannot access memory at address 0x55555556d>

The uninitialized_copy is written wrong in the book so maybe there's something else missing? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Update 17.08:** I added constructors, destructors, copy and move operations for vector_base and vector (inspired from C++ Programming Language) and now it works. Thanks for the replies!

**I have a question:** "Programing Principles and Practice" makes vector class a derivate of vector_base class while "C++ Programming Language" makes a vector_base object a data member of class vector. I wonder which option is better? They seem equivalent though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class allocator
{
public:
    T *allocate(int n) { return (T *)malloc(n * sizeof(T)); } // allocate space for n objects of type T
    void construct(T *p, const T &v) { new (p) T{v}; }        // construct a T with the value v in p
    void destroy(T *p) { p->~T(); }                           // destroy the T in p
    void deallocate(T *p, int n) { free(p); }                 // deallocate n objects of type T starting at p
};

template <typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>
struct vector_base
{
    A alloc;   // allocator,
    T *elem;   // start of allocation
    int sz;    // number of elements
    int space; // amount of allocated space

    vector_base()
        : sz{0}, elem{nullptr}, space{0} {}
    vector_base(const A &a, int n)
        : alloc{a}, elem{alloc.allocate(n)}, sz{0}, space{n} 
    {
    }
    ~vector_base() { alloc.deallocate(elem, space); }

    vector_base(const vector_base &) = delete; // no copy operations
    vector_base &operator=(const vector_base &) = delete;
    vector_base(vector_base &&); // move operations
    vector_base &operator=(vector_base &&);
};

template <class T, class A>
vector_base<T, A>::vector_base(vector_base &&a)              // move constructor
    : alloc{a.alloc}, elem{a.elem}, sz{a.sz}, space{a.space} // no free space if space{a.sz}
{
    a.elem = nullptr;
    a.sz = a.space = 0;
}
template <class T, class A>
vector_base<T, A> &vector_base<T, A>::operator=(vector_base &&a) // move assignment
{
    elem = a.elem;
    sz = a.sz;
    space = a.space; // also move space
    a.elem = nullptr;
    a.sz = a.space = 0;
    return *this;
    // swap(*this, a); // also works
    // return *this;
}

template <typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>
class vector : private vector_base<T, A>
{
public:
    vector()
        : vector_base<T, A>() {}

    explicit vector(int s);
    vector(std::initializer_list<T> lst); // 18.2 initializer-list constructor
    vector(const vector &);               // copy constructor
    vector &operator=(const vector &);    // copy assignment

    vector(vector &&);            // move constructor
    vector &operator=(vector &&); // move assignment

    ~vector(); // destructor

    T &operator[](int n) { return this->elem[n]; }
    const T &operator[](int n) const { return this->elem[n]; }
    int size() const { return this->sz; }
    int capacity() const { return this->space; }
    T *get_elem() const { return this->elem; }  
    A get_alloc() const { return this->alloc; } 
    void reserve(int newalloc);
    void push_back(const T &d);
    void resize(int newsize, T val = T());
};

template <typename T, typename A>
vector<T, A>::vector(int s)
    : vector_base<T, A>(this->alloc, s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)                     
        this->alloc.construct(&this->elem[i], T()); 
}
template <typename T, typename A>
vector<T, A>::vector(std::initializer_list<T> lst) 
    : vector_base<T, A>(this->alloc, lst.size())   
{
    std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), this->elem); 
    this->sz = lst.size();                         
}
template <typename T, typename A>
vector<T, A>::vector(const vector &a) // copy constructor
    : vector_base<T, A>(a.alloc, a.size())
{
    uninitialized_copy(a.elem, a.elem + a.sz, this->elem); 
    this->sz = a.sz;
}
template <typename T, typename A>
vector<T, A> &vector<T, A>::operator=(const vector &a) // copy assignment
{
    if (this == &a) // self-assignment, no work needed
        return *this;
    if (a.sz <= this->space) // enough space, no need for new allocation 
    {
        uninitialized_copy(a.get_elem(), &a.get_elem()[a.size()], this->elem);
        this->sz = a.sz;
    }
    // took it from C++ Programming Language
    vector temp{a}; // copy allocator
    std::swap(*this, temp);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T, typename A> // move constructor
vector<T, A>::vector(vector &&a)
    : vector_base<T, A>(a.alloc, a.size()) // get a's data members (alloc, elem, space)
{
    this->sz = a.sz; // also get a's size
    a.elem = nullptr;
    a.sz = a.space = 0;
}
template <typename T, typename A>
vector<T, A> &vector<T, A>::operator=(vector<T, A> &&a) // move assignment
//: vector_base<T, A>(a.alloc, a.size())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->sz; ++i)
        this->alloc.destroy(&this->elem[i]);
    this->alloc.deallocate(this->elem, this->space);

    this->elem = a.elem;
    this->sz = a.sz;
    this->space = a.space;
    a.elem = nullptr;
    a.sz = a.space = 0;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T, typename A>
vector<T, A>::~vector() // destructor
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->sz; ++i)
        this->alloc.destroy(&this->elem[i]); 
}

template <typename T, typename A>
void print(const vector<T, A> &v, const std::string &s)
{
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << s << ' ' << "size: " << v.size() << ' ' << "capacity: " << v.capacity() << ' ';
    std::cout << "elements: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename T, typename A>
void vector<T, A>::reserve(int newalloc)
{
    if (newalloc <= this->space)
        return;                                 // never decrease allocation
    vector_base<T, A> b(this->alloc, newalloc); // allocate new space
    uninitialized_copy(this->elem, &this->elem[size()], b.elem); // copy from caller of reserve() to b
    b.sz = this->sz;                                             // vector_base b has size = 0 because of the constructor so you have to change it
    for (int i = 0; i < this->sz; ++i)
        this->alloc.destroy(&this->elem[i]); // destroy old
    std::swap<vector_base<T, A>>(*this, b); // swap representations
} // at exit ~vector_base will deallocate b

template <typename T, typename A> // 19.3.7
void vector<T, A>::push_back(const T &val)
{
    if (this->space == 0)
        reserve(8);
    else if (this->sz == this->space)
        reserve(2 * this->space);
    this->alloc.construct(&this->elem[this->sz], val); // add val to position sz
    ++this->sz;
}
template <typename T, typename A>
void vector<T, A>::resize(int newsize, T val) //  deleted =T() from here
{
    reserve(newsize);
    for (int i = this->sz; i < newsize; ++i)  // if newsize is bigger than currect size construct default values
        this->alloc.construct(&this->elem[i], val); // construct
    for (int i = newsize; i < this->sz; ++i)   // if newsize is smaller than currenct size destroy the elements
        this->alloc.destroy(&this->elem[i]); // destroy
    this->sz = this->space= newsize; // reset space - like in C++PL

}

int main()
try
{
   vector<std::string> vs;
    vs.push_back("test");
    print(vs, "vs.push_back():");
    vs.reserve(10);
    print(vs, "vs.reserve(10):");
}
catch (std::exception &e)
{
    std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "exception\n";
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever rely on pointers to a `std::vector`s internal `data` section when manipulating the `std::vector` instance.

Comment: Which edition of the book? Did you check the errata?

Comment: 2nd edition and the errata doesn't say anything at chapter 19: https://www.stroustrup.com/PPPslides/PPP2errata.html

Comment: `std::swap` in this case utilizes the default move constructor and/or move assignment operator(I'm not sure which of those are involved right now, but at least one of them). So the value of `T *elem` is copied from `b` to `*this` so both have the same address -> double free. Are you sure there wasn't a move constructor and/or assignment operator introduced somewhere in the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `vector_base` in the example fails to follow the rule of 5 (previously, of 3). It implements a destructor where it releases a resource, but doesn't implement copy / move constructors nor assignment operators to handle that. When `reserve` calls `swap` with `vector_base` arguments, it will move (previously copy) the instance, then do two move (previously copy) assignments after which the intermediate object is destroyed... and that destructor frees the same pointer that is still owned by one of the arguments which results in undefined behaviour when the pointer is freed again in the destructor of that object.

One correct C++03 implementation would be to remove `~vector_base()` and instead deallocate at the end of `vector::reserve` and `vector::~vector` (which needs to be added). Or maybe you could use `std::auto_ptr` in `vector_base`. You also need to define copy constructor and assignment operator of the vector.

In C++11 and later, you would define the move constructor and assignment operator for `vector_base`.

Comment: The book has the vector move constructor and other required stuff. The example above is not from the book, but assembled by OP from the parts in the book.

Comment: thanks eerorika! I'll implement them and see how it works

Comment: @Theodore This source code of the book doesn't have `vector_base` at all: https://github.com/Chrinkus/stroustrup-ppp/blob/master/chapter19/ch19_vector.h

Comment: This is the version before sub-chapter 19.5.6 where vector_base is introduced. And it works fine indeed.